Trying to copy a file from one dir to another using part of a name/serial number
So i am trying to create a script that will do several things, but first i need to copy stuff.
I need to copy all files from directory A to B using a user input that will specify the files to be copied based on a serial number or part of one.
I.e. After user types the sn "###" and chooses the folder X or Y, i want the all files in the folder with Test_1_051724###.txt to be copied to directory B.
Here is what i have so far. In the end i need to grab the files out of a linux pc connected via eathernet, but I can change the addresses later once I figure out what im doing wrong with the copy bit.
I have been able to create a dir and copy files when I input "test" but any time i use a number I doe not copy. I tried a few things and haven't been able to figure out what im doing wrong or missing.
Some guidenc would be great.
Thank you.
I attempted a different approach and I am getting error:
@echo off
:start

rem Prompt the user for the search string
set /p search_string=Enter the search string: 

rem Prompt the user to choose the source directory
echo Choose the source directory:
echo 1. EE1
echo 2. EE2
set /p source_dir_choice=Enter 1 or 2: 


rem Set the source directory based on the user's choice
if %source_dir_choice% == 1 (
    set source_dir="C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\."
    set dest_dir="C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\TestMove1"
) else if %source_dir_choice% == 2 (
    set source_dir="C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\."
    set dest_dir="C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\TestMove2"
) else (
    echo Invalid choice. Exiting.
    goto end
)



@REM rem destination directory
@REM if %source_dir_choice% == 1 (
@REM     set dest_dir=C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\TestMove1
@REM ) else if %source_dir_choice% == 2 (
@REM     set dest_dir=C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\TestMove2
@REM ) else (
@REM     echo Invalid choice. Exiting...
@REM     goto start
@REM )


rem Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
if not exist "%dest_dir%" mkdir "%dest_dir%"

rem Copy the files that contain the search string
for %%f in ("%source_dir%\*") do (
    if "%%~nxf" gtr "" if "%%~nxf" lss "" if "%%~nxf" contains "%search_string%" (
        copy "%%f" "%dest_dir%"
        echo Copied file: %%~nxf
    )
)

echo.
echo File copy complete.
echo.

goto start

:end

I did get this one to kind of work, but it only seems to want to copy a file when the word is in the beginning.
@echo off
:start

rem Prompt the user for the partial file name
set /p partial_filename=Enter the partial file name: 

rem Prompt the user to choose the source directory
echo Choose the source directory:
echo 1. C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1
echo 2. C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE2
set /p source_dir_choice=Enter 1 or 2: 

rem Set the source directory based on the user's choice
if %source_dir_choice% == 1 (
    set source_dir=C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1
) else if %source_dir_choice% == 2 (
    set source_dir=C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE2
) else (
    echo Invalid choice. Exiting.
    goto end
)

rem Set the destination directory
set dest_dir=C:\Users\cliljohn\Documents\DCD\EE1\TestMove

rem Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
if not exist "%dest_dir%" mkdir "%dest_dir%"

rem Copy the files that match the partial file name
for %%f in ("%source_dir%\%partial_filename%*") do (
    copy "%%f" "%dest_dir%"
    echo Copied file: %%~nxf
)

echo File copy complete.


@REM goto start
:end



if "%%~nf" == "%serial_number%" will only be true if the base filename is exactly the serial number that the user inputs.  It does not match partial filenames.

Where in the help file for the IF command did you see this syntax? if "%%~nxf" contains "%search_string%"

Use multiple wild card characters to match the partial filename. example: *myfile*

There seems to be a few issues with your example code, and your task is also a little unclear. Here therefore is quick example to possibly help you out, and give you something to research.
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:GetStr
Set "search_string="
Set /P "search_string=Enter the search string: " 2>NUL || GoTo GetStr

:GetDir
Set "source_dir="
Echo Source directories:
Echo 1. EE1
Echo 2. EE2
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
If Exist "%UserProfile%\Documents\DCD\EE%ErrorLevel%\." (
    Set "source_dir=%UserProfile%\Documents\DCD\EE%ErrorLevel%"
    Set "dest_dir=%UserProfile%\Documents\DCD\EE%ErrorLevel%\TestMove%ErrorLevel%"
)
If Not Defined source_dir GoTo GetDir
%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%source_dir%" "%destdir%" "*%search_string%.*"

%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Would you like to select again"
If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B
GoTo GetStr

